# Why does object_getIvar return null?

Tags: objective-c, null

Why does the following objective-c code print 
name : (null)
but if the NSLog(@"Country name : %@", c.name); is uncommented then it prints:
Country name : USA
name : USA

```
 Country *c = row;
 //NSLog(@"Country name : %@", c.name);
 Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([row class], "name");
 NSString *name = object_getIvar(row, ivar);
 NSLog(@"name : %@", name);
```

Comment: try to pause the execution....

Comment: what if you use `object_getInstanceVariable` directly?

Comment: Pause Execution seems to work -> if I put it in a UITable and access it later it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I avoid this problem by using properties instead of iVars. Then you can use `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:` to get and set the properties.

Here is the Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the property `name` is backed by an autogenerated instance variable called `_name`. Try

```
Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([row class], "_name");
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs it states:

> object_getIvar is faster than object_getInstanceVariable if the Ivar for the instance variable is already known.

This implies that maybe your ivar needs to be "known". That would explain why it gets printed correctly after having been retrieved in your log statement. Go with `object_getInstanceVariable`.

Please note that the documentation also states the following. You would have to have a real good reason to get into this low-level stuff:

> This reference is useful primarily for developing bridge layers between Objective-C and other languages, or for low-level debugging. You typically do not need to use the Objective-C runtime library directly when programming in Objective-C.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, but it is a hint, and the answer includes a working solution.

Comment: I can't use this function because of ARC : 'object_getInstanceVariable' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

Comment: Any other way to make it known?

Comment: Perhaps with `[(Country*)row name];`? The documentation states explicitly that you do not need these functions when programming objective-c -- only if you want to write "bridge layers".

Comment: The Objective-C Runtime Reference does not provide a thorough range of applications to which the runtime may be purposed.  Objective-C proper has weak introspection abilities; knowledgeable and careful use of the runtime can be utilized to fill such gaps.